# Proportional image resize in Coldfusion 9

Tags: performance, image, coldfusion, resize, coldfusion-9

I have a function which should resize all images in given folders (I don't know exactly how much, but I guess 2500+) and save them to a diffrent folder:

```
<CFSET base = expandpath("./images") />
<CFSET folders = listtoarray("folder1,folder2") />
<CFLOOP array="#folders#" index="folder">
  <CFDIRECTORY name="qImages" directory="#base#/#folder#/big/" action="list" listinfo="name" type="file" filter="*.jpg" />
  <CFLOOP query="qBilder">
    <CFIMAGE action="resize" height="" width="320" source="#base#/#folder#/big/#name#" destination="#base#/#folder#/#name#" overwrite="yes" />
  </CFLOOP>
</CFLOOP>
```

I wonder how to do this more efficient than I do?! I read that in CF there are **[17 different algorithms for resizing images](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2008/3/28/Ask-a-Jedi-CFIMAGE-performance-concerns)**. Which would be the most performant one with a good mix of image quality and speed?

Comment: is this a once-off procedure or something that will run more often?

Comment: just ran one time .. but took about 30mins with heavy cpu load

Comment: for a once-off task i wouldnt do it with coldfusion to be honest - unless i had no other access to the server/files

Comment: imageResize() has an interpolation parameter. this can be set to many values like highestQuality or highestPerformance. [documentation here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_i_02.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may test the performance of `imageResize()` first.  As jan said, play with the "interpolation parameter" to get your quality vs speed.  If it is proven too slow / too ugly for you, use [ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

Set your interpolation to "highestPerformance" for images <= 100x100 pixels and "highestQuality" or "lanczos" for the rest. If you are creating .jpgs the default quality is 0.75 which means 75%. For tiny images, drop this to 0.5 or less for quick low quality images.

If you want a proportional resize, provide imageResize() with a width or height, but not both.

http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#imageresize